# Convert Dataframe into (first panel of) 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following Dataframe named `df1`:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | 15 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 | 30 |

Now, let's say I also have the following blank 3D array (created just as placeholder for now):

```
array1 = np.zeros((10,3,2))
```

With `df1` having the same number of rows and columns, how can I replace the 1st "panel" (of ten "panels") in `array1` with `df1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly assign the DataFrame to the first "panel":

```
array1[0] = df

print(array1)
# Output:
[[[ 5. 10.]
  [15. 20.]
  [25. 30.]]

 [[ 0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.]]
# ...followed by 7 more identical 3x2 zero matrices
```

Out of habit, I first tried `array1[0, :, :] = df.to_numpy()`, which gives the same result, as far as I can tell, but is more explicit in its intent.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
array1[0] = df1
```

Output:

```
>>> array1
array([[[ 5., 10.],
        [15., 20.],
        [25., 30.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

        ...

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

you can directly assign like richardec mentioned

```
array1[0] = df1
```

you can also try this to know what is happening internally

```
array=np.array(df)
array1[0]=array
```

output is same in both the cases

```
array([[[ 5., 10.],
        [15., 20.],
        [25., 30.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Also,  `array=np.array(df)` is the same as `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: I didn't completely go through your answer when i was answering this question but u came up with simple and compact solution.